# Performance: Java's String.format

Tags: java, performance, string-concatenation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I use Java's String.format() if performance is important?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513600/should-i-use-javas-string-format-if-performance-is-important)

I was wondering if is good to use `String.format` in Java apps instead of `StringBuilder`... so, I just write a simple test, like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 0;
        Long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (i < 10000) {
            String s = String.format("test %d", i);
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
        i = 0;
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (i < 10000) {
            String s = new StringBuilder().append("test ").append(i).toString();
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
    }
```

And the results where:

```
238
15
```

So, if my test is valid, `StringBuilder` is faster than `String.format`. OK.
Now, I start thinking how `String.format` works. Is it a simple String concatenation, like `"test " + i`?

What the differences between `StringBuilder` concatenation and `String.format`? Is there a way simple as `String.format` and fast like `StringBuilder`?

Comment: One important assumption in your post is: *"if my test is valid"* ;-) You should read about [how to create a micro benchmark in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java).

Comment: Remember that the first case is actually `String.format("test %d", new Object[]{new Integer(i)})` which may account for a significant proportion of the overhead if the compiler isn't sufficiently clever.

Comment: `String.format` has to parse the format string each time, then do some fairly dynamic stuff to convert the arguments. Approaches using `StringBuilder` don't; the sequence of actions needed to build the string comes from the bytecode. Parsing and effectively executing a format string is likely to be orders of magnitude string than executing code.

Comment: Why do you even compare those? Try writing something like `String.format("% 5.3f")` using StringBuilder, then you'll understand why it's slower.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I wrote a quick [caliper](http://code.google.com/p/caliper/) benchmark to compare `String.format()` vs. `StringBuilder`, `StringBuffer`, normal `String` `+` operator, `String.replace()` and `String.concat()` methods:

```
public class StringFormatBenchmark extends SimpleBenchmark {

    public void timeStringFormat(int reps) {
        while (--reps >= 0) {
            String s = String.format("test %d", reps);
        }
    }

    public void timeStringBuilder(int reps) {
        while (--reps >= 0) {
            String s = new StringBuilder("test ").append(reps).toString();
        }
    }

    public void timeStringBuffer(int reps) {
        while (--reps >= 0) {
            String s = new StringBuffer("test ").append(reps).toString();
        }
    }

    public void timeStringPlusOperator(int reps) {
        while (--reps >= 0) {
            String s = "test " + reps;
        }
    }

    public void timeReplace(int reps) {
        while (--reps >= 0) {
            String s = "test {}".replace("{}", String.valueOf(reps));
        }
    }

    public void timeStringConcat(int reps) {
        while (--reps >= 0) {
            String s = "test ".concat(String.valueOf(reps));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Runner().run(StringFormatBenchmark.class.getName());
    }

}
```

The results follow (Java 1.6.0_26-b03, Ubuntu, 32 bits):

[image: caliper2]

Clearly `String.format()` is much slower (by an order of magnitude). Also `StringBuffer` is considerably slower than `StringBuilder` (as we were taught). Finally `StringBuilder` and `String` `+` operator are almost identical since they compile to very similar bytecode. `String.concat()` is a bit slower.

Also don't use `String.replace()` if simple concatenation is sufficient.

Comment: It would be nice if you added `"test ".concat(String.valueOf(reps))` to the benchmarks since the special case of two concatenation operands is more likely to compile into that form (no benefit of a builder for a single operation).

Comment: thanks, very nice tests.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: so I did, thanks for the tip, I updated my benchmark and results. Feel free to run the test on you machine.

Comment: I ran it (Java 7, OS X), and the gap between `concat` and `StringBuilder` is even wider. That surprises me, `concat` ostensibly does less work (for example, only one `char[]` allocation). The `+` operator is even in this case compiled using `StringBuilder` (this, of course, depends on the compiler used; I used Eclipse's).

Comment: It's very important not to leap to hasty conclusions from the picture you created! Your test measures the time for **one** string operation! (The loops are only for test accuracy.) If you build a string in a loop, `StringBuffer` and `StringBuilder` are **much** faster than the `+` operator. Example result: The `+` operator may take more than a minute to build the a string of 500000 characters where `StringBu{ffer,ilder}` build the exact same string in less than 50ms!

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik This whole benchmark can be completely optimized away as the strings gets never used. Summing their lengths would help.

Comment: @steffen Right, but then you could do something like `builder.append(String.format(...)` in order to get both readability and some speed. Appending to a string in a loop is indeed not an option.

Answer (score 3):

String.format is relatively slower but usually more than fast enough.

I would use format if that is simpler, unless you can see a performance issue when you profile your application.

Note: The String.format in your example is taking ~24 micro-seconds and won't be fully warmed up yet.  I would ignore the first 10K iterations.

IMHO `"test " + i` is the simplest in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I have run a test post-JVM warmup (once the methods are compiled) and get similar results, with StringBuilder more than 30x quicker.

> format: 943
>   stringbuilder: 26

```
public class TestPerf {

    private static int NUM_RUN;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NUM_RUN = 100_000;
        //warm up
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            method1();
            method2();
        }

        System.gc();
        System.out.println("Starting");

        long sum = 0;
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            sum += method1();
        }
        long end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("format: " + (end - start) / 1000000);

        System.gc();

        start = System.nanoTime();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            sum += method2();
        }
        end = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("stringbuilder: " + (end - start) / 1000000);

        System.out.println(sum);
    }

    private static int method1() {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_RUN; i++) {
            String s = String.format("test %d", i);
            sum += s.length();
        }
        return sum;
    }

    private static int method2() {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_RUN; i++) {
            String s = new StringBuilder().append("test ").append(i).toString();
            sum += s.length();
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```