# Get Values from List and insert into String

Tags: java, list

I have a string where i need to place the values from the list,But when i for loop the list i will get one value at a iteration.

```
public class Test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, JSONException {

        List<String> value=new ArrayList<String>();
        value.add("RAM");
        value.add("26");
        value.add("INDIA");

        for(int i=0;i<value.size();i++){
        String template="My name is "+value.get(i) +"  age is "+value.get(i)+" country is"+value.get(i);
        System.out.println(value.get(i));
        }
    o/p should be like this:    String ="My name is +"+RAM +"age is "+26+"Country is"+INDIA;
    }
}
```

Comment: welcome to Java.  Use a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: And what is your output? Did you try changing something

Comment: What makes you think a for loop would be a good solution here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening is that in each iteration you're taking the i-th element of the list and you're placing it in all the positions of your String template.

As @javaguy says, there's no need to use a `for` loop if you only have those three items in your list, and another solution is to use `String.format`:

```
String template = "My name is %s age is %s country is %s";
String output = String.format(template, value.get(0), value.get(1), value.get(2));
```

It's probably a bit slower (interesting discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513600/should-i-use-javas-string-format-if-performance-is-important)) but performances don't seem to be relevant in your case, so the choiche between the two options would be mostly based on personal taste.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `for` loop, simply access the elements using `index` of the `List` as shown below:

```
System.out.println("My name is "+value.get(0) +
  "  age is "+value.get(1)+" country is"+value.get(2));
```

Also, I suggest you use `StringBuilder` for appending strings which is a best practice, as shown below:

```
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        output.append("My name is ").append(value.get(0)).append("  age is ").
            append(value.get(1)).append(" country is ").append(value.get(2));
System.out.println(output.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need any loop! Also you do not need any array list I am sorry but I could fully understand what exactly you need but I this code will help you:

```
    List<String> value = new ArrayList<String>();
    value.add("RAM");
    value.add("26");
    value.add("INDIA");

    String template = "My name is " + value.get(0) + "  age is " + value.get(1) + " country is" + value.get(2);
    System.out.println(template);

    // o/p should be like this: String ="My name is +"+RAM +"age is
    // "+26+"Country is"+INDIA;
```