# Performance between String.format and StringBuilder

Tags: java, stringbuilder, string.format

To concatenate `String` we often use `StringBuilder` instead of `String` + `String`, but also we can do the same with `String.format` which returns the formatted string by given locale, format and arguments.

Examples:

**Concatenate the string with StringBuilder**

```
String concatenateStringWithStringBuilder(String name, String lName, String nick) {
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Contact {");
    sb.append(", name='").append(name)
      .append(", lastName='").append(lName)
      .append(", nickName='").append(nick)
      .append('}');
    return sb.toString();
}
```

**Concatenate the string with StringFormat:**

```
String concatenateStringWithStringFormat(String name, String lName, String nick) {
    return String.format("Contact {name=%s, lastName=%s, nickName=%s}", name, lName, nick);
}
```

In performance, is `String.Format` as efficient as `StringBuilder`? Which one is better to concatenate strings and why?

**UPDATE**

I checked the similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513600/should-i-use-javas-string-format-if-performance-is-important), but doesn´t answer my question. So far I have used `StringBuilder` to concatenate strings, should I follow it using? Or should I use `String.format`? the question is which one is better and why?

Comment: A quick benchmark won't take too much time

Comment: A third option: `return "Contact {name=" + name + ", lastName=" + lName + ", nickName=" + nick + '}';` This would create the same bytecode as using StringBuilder and is just as readable as using String.Format.

Comment: see this
[Should I use Java's String.format() if performance is important?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513600/should-i-use-javas-string-format-if-performance-is-important)

Comment: Unless your method is being called thousands of times per second, you will not notice a difference in performance.  You should not use StringBuilder or StringBuffer, simply because they are so much less readable.  I would use String.format, because it makes very clear what your final string is intended to look like.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After doing a little test with `StringBuilder` vs `String.format` I understood how much time it takes each of them to solve the concatenation. Here the snippet code and the results

**Code:**

```
String name = "stackover";
String lName = " flow";
String nick = " stackoverflow";
String email = "stackoverflow@email.com";
int phone = 123123123;

//for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
long initialTime1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
String response = String.format(" - Contact {name=%s, lastName=%s, nickName=%s, email=%s, phone=%d}",
                                name, lName, nick, email, phone);
long finalTime1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
long totalTime1 = finalTime1 - initialTime1;
System.out.println(totalTime1 + response);

long initialTime2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(" - Contact {");
sb.append("name=").append(name)
  .append(", lastName=").append(lName)
  .append(", nickName=").append(nick)
  .append(", email=").append(email)
  .append(", phone=").append(phone)
  .append('}');
String response2 = sb.toString();
long finalTime2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
long totalTime2 = finalTime2 - initialTime2;
System.out.println(totalTime2 + response2);
//}
```

After of run the code several times, I saw that `String.format` takes more time:

```
String.format: 46: Contact {name=stackover, lastName= flow, nickName= stackoverflow, email=stackoverflow@email.com, phone=123123123}
StringBuilder: 0: Contact {name=stackover, lastName= flow, nickName= stackoverflow, email=stackoverflow@email.com, phone=123123123}
String.format: 38: Contact {name=stackover, lastName= flow, nickName= stackoverflow, email=stackoverflow@email.com, phone=123123123}
StringBuilder: 0: Contact {name=stackover, lastName= flow, nickName= stackoverflow, email=stackoverflow@email.com, phone=123123123}
String.format: 51: Contact {name=stackover, lastName= flow, nickName= stackoverflow, email=stackoverflow@email.com, phone=123123123}
StringBuilder: 0: Contact {name=stackover, lastName= flow, nickName= stackoverflow, email=stackoverflow@email.com, phone=123123123}
```

But if I run the same code inside a loop, the result change.

```
String.format: 43: Contact {name=stackover, lastName= flow, nickName= stackoverflow, email=stackoverflow@email.com, phone=123123123}
StringBuilder: 0: Contact {name=stackover, lastName= flow, nickName= stackoverflow, email=stackoverflow@email.com, phone=123123123}
String.format: 1: Contact {name=stackover, lastName= flow, nickName= stackoverflow, email=stackoverflow@email.com, phone=123123123}
StringBuilder: 0: Contact {name=stackover, lastName= flow, nickName= stackoverflow, email=stackoverflow@email.com, phone=123123123}
String.format: 1: Contact {name=stackover, lastName= flow, nickName= stackoverflow, email=stackoverflow@email.com, phone=123123123}
StringBuilder: 0: Contact {name=stackover, lastName= flow, nickName= stackoverflow, email=stackoverflow@email.com, phone=123123123}
```

The first time `String.format` runs it takes more time, after of that the time is shorter even though it does not become constant as a result of `StringBuilder`

As @G.Fiedler said: "`String.format` has to parse the format string..."

With these results it can be said that `StringBuilder` is more efficient than`String.format`

Comment: You could also test `String,concat` on either long and short strings

Comment: Interesting idea to test the loop.  It seems like the parsed format string is cached and reused instead of being parsed again on each loop iteration. 
 Also, it makes since that StringBuilder is slower on subsequent loop iterations, because you are instantiating an entirely new StringBuilder on each iteration (assuming you literally just wrapped the same code with a loop).

Answer (score 38):

What is "better" solely depends on your requirements:

- For instance `String Builder` will be faster, but the code will be much more unreadable, and and it would be easier to make a mistake.
- On the other hand `String.format()` produces more readable code at the cost of performance.

JMH benchmark to illustrate the performance difference (notice that the string builder code is longer and very hard to understand how the resulting string would look like):

```
@Fork(1)
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@Measurement(iterations = 10)
@Warmup(iterations = 10)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.Throughput)
public class StringFormatBenchmark {
    private String name = "UserName";
    private String lName = "LUserName";
    private String nick = "UserNick";

    @Benchmark
    public void stringFormat(Blackhole blackhole) {
        final String result = String.format("Contact {name=%s, lastName=%s, nickName=%s}", name, lName, nick);
        blackhole.consume(result);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public void stringBuilder(Blackhole blackhole) {
        final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("Contact {");
        sb.append(", name='").append(name)
                .append(", lastName='").append(lName)
                .append(", nickName='").append(nick)
                .append('}');
        final String result = sb.toString();
        blackhole.consume(result);
    }
}
```

And the results:

```
Benchmark                             Mode  Cnt      Score     Error   Units
StringFormatBenchmark.stringBuilder  thrpt   10  10617.210 ± 157.302  ops/ms
StringFormatBenchmark.stringFormat   thrpt   10    960.658 ±   7.398  ops/ms
```

For non performance critical code I prefer using the `String.format()`, because it's easier and more pleasant to use. Also it's visible what the resulting string would look like, by simply looking at the pattern. If I'm doing a performance critical code, or something that has to have a low GC impact, I would use a `StringBuilder` because it's faster and can be reused.

Comment: how did you run it may I ask?

Comment: @FarazDurrani Just run the "Launcher" with the test class name as parameter: https://github.com/SvetlinZarev/com.github.svetlinzarev.jmh.benchmarks/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/svetlinzarev/jmh/benchmarks/Launcher.java

Comment: Thanks @Svetlin. I was able to run other JMH from google. But thanks though.

Comment: I actually see StringBuilder as more readable and less prone to mistakes. I'm not used to the symbols of String.format(). And String.format() I need to pay more attention to the order of the itens, while in StringBuilder it's 1 per line, it's more organized.

Answer (score 13):

`StringBuilder` is faster, because `String.format` has to parse the format string (a complex domain specific language). And that's expensive.

> StringBuilder instead of String + String

BTW: It's the same, because it results in the same byte code (since Java 1.5).