# Multiple StringBuilders inside StringBuilder. Does it worth?

Tags: java, string, performance, concatenation, stringbuilder

I receive a list of models. The number of models could be large. This models has a bunch of properties and any of them could be *null* potentially.

I need to build a string for every model based of it's properties. If **property == null** then I add some static part to the result string like *"property1 is null"*.

If else **property != null** then I add something like this *"property1 == 'valueOfThePropertyHere'"*.

The result string should look something like this:
`prop1 == 'value1' and prop2 is null and prop3 == 'value3' and prop4 == 'value4' and prop5 is null and ..... propN == 'valueN'`

And I generate such string for every model from the list.

Obviously I do this in for loop and I use StringBuilder for this. The thing is that in **append** method of StringBuilder I check every field of the model for null using ternary operator and based on this I add the result of this check to the result string. But if a property is not null then I need to add some static part + value of the field itself + some more static stuff. And that means I need to add one more StringBuilder for every property I have. Or I can use '+' which will be transformed into StringBuilder anyway and as far as I know it's a bad practise to use '+' inside StringBuilder (but I have to use it anyway).

Example:

```java
List<Model> models = repository.getModels();

for (Model m: models) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    stringBuilder
    .append(m.getField1() == null ? "field1  is null" : "field1 == '" + new StringBuiler().append(m.getField1()).append("'").append(" and ").toString()))
    .append(m.getField2() == null ? "field2  is null" : "field2 == '" + new StringBuiler().append(m.getField2()).append("'").append(" and ").toString()))
    ...............
    .append(m.getFieldN() == null ? "fieldN  is null" : "fieldN == '" + new StringBuiler().append(m.getFieldN()).append("'").append(" and ").toString()));

    System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
    }
```

In my opinion from the performance perspective it doesn't look so well because for every model from a list of models I create another bunch of StringBuilder objects in heap just to get the result string.

Am I missing something? Are there better ways to do so from the performance perspective? Or it's okay because I don't see other options for now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513600/should-i-use-javas-string-format-if-performance-is-important has some information regarding the available options and their speed.

Comment: *"In my opinion from the performance perspective it doesn't look so well"* I disagree because the performance perspective here is so incredibly microscopic that you'll have trouble even measuring any differences. Let the compiler + JVM + hotspot worry about micro optimizations, you just write good, clean code.

Comment: Creating a new StringBuilder just to immediately append 3 things and call toString() is defeating the purpose of the StringBuilder

Comment: Just use `if/else`, and append directly to the main `StringBuilder`.

Comment: How many models might you receive? Generally programmers optimize prematurely, and should code for clarity.

Comment: @AndyMan hundreds. Might get around a thousand.

Comment: method getting the `StringBuilder` and `if` inside to avoid another concatenation, I would say... (short methods are very easy for JIT to inline) - despite in newer Java versions tests are required: string concatenation is not done with `StringBuilder`anymore

Comment: BTW `new StringBuilder().append(a).append(b)...toString()` is what compiler did for `a+b+...` (but later is easier to read)

Comment: @Coffeemanz Just a 1000? Go for simple and clear. If you're worried, add a log statement with the time it took.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go for simple.

Instead of

```
stringBuilder
.append(m.getField1() == null ? "field1  is null" : "field1 == '" + new StringBuiler().append(m.getField1()).append("'").append(" and ").toString()))
```

use:

```
if (m.getField1() == null) {
  stringBuilder.append("field1  is null");
} else {
  stringBuilder.append("field1 == '").append(m.getField1()).append("'").append(" and ");
}
```

Aside from the distinct oddness of using a `StringBuilder` inside a `StringBuilder.append` call (and why not just use `+` anyway...), it's really hard to parse where the `:` is in the conditional expression. Breaking it into lines is much easier.

---

If you find yourself having to repeat this code pattern a lot, define a method:

```
void append(StringBuilder stringBuilder, String name, Object value) {
  stringBuilder.append(name);
  if (value == null) {
    stringBuilder.append(" is null");
  } else {
    stringBuilder.append(" == '").append(value).append("'").append(" and ");
  }
}
```

and then invoke like:

```
append(stringBuilder, "field1", m.getField1());
append(stringBuilder, "field2", m.getField2());
append(stringBuilder, "field3", m.getField3());
```

Comment: Mind the missing "and" in the == null case.

Comment: @AndyMan seems reasonable. Wanted to make it compact (if it's possible to say so in this case) as much as it's possible.

Comment: @Coffemanz 'compact 'and 'performance perspective' are very different...

Comment: If you want compact, then just drop the second StringBuilder  and instead use strings like " == " + value + "' and ".  Java uses StringBuilder internally so they are equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

What a mess! Just because you *can* chain invocations, doesn't mean you should:

```
List<Model> models = repository.getModels();

    for (Model m: models) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        String field = m.getField1();
        if(field==null) {
            stringBuilder.append("field1 is null");
        } else {
            stringBuilder.append("field1 == ").append(m.getField1()).append("'");
        }

        if(stringBuilder.length()>0) {
            stringBuilder.append(" and ");
        }

        field = m.getField2();
        if(field==null) {
            stringBuilder.append("field2 is null");
        } else {
            stringBuilder.append("field2 == ").append(m.getField1()).append("'");
        }

        if(stringBuilder.length()>0) {
            stringBuilder.append(" and ");
        }
        ...

        System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
    }
```

To avoid all this potential repetition (depending on number of fields):

```
void appendField(StringBuilder stringBuilder, String fieldName, String value) {
    if(stringBuilder.length()>0) {
        stringBuilder.append(" and ");
    }
    stringBuilder.append(fieldName);
    if(value==null) {
        stringBuilder.append(" is null");
    } else {
        stringBuilder.append(" == '").append(value).append("'");
    }
}
String toString(Model m) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    appendField(stringBuilder, "field1", m.getField1());
    appendField(stringBuilder, "field2", m.getField2());
    ...
    appendField(stringBuilder, "fieldN", m.getFieldN());

    return stringBuilder.toString();
}

List<Model> models = repository.getModels();

for (Model m: models) {
    System.out.println(toString(m));
}
```